# How could sys_sigsuspend is atomical in linux kernel 2.6.11?

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm reading linux 2.6.11
the implementation of sys_sigsuspend is as the following

```
 34 /*
 35  * Atomically swap in the new signal mask, and wait for a signal.
 36  */
 37 asmlinkage int
 38 sys_sigsuspend(int history0, int history1, old_sigset_t mask)
 39 {
 40         struct pt_regs * regs = (struct pt_regs *) &history0;
 41         sigset_t saveset;
 42 
 43         mask &= _BLOCKABLE;
 44         spin_lock_irq(&current->sighand->siglock);
 45         saveset = current->blocked;
 46         siginitset(&current->blocked, mask);
 47         recalc_sigpending();
 48         spin_unlock_irq(&current->sighand->siglock);
 49 
 50         regs->eax = -EINTR;
 51         while (1) {
 52                 current->state = TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE;
 53                 schedule();
 54                 if (do_signal(regs, &saveset))
 55                         return -EINTR;
 56         }
 57 }
```

in ULK3 the author says

> the sigsuspend( ) system call does not allow signals to be sent after unblocking and before the schedule( ) invocation, because other processes cannot grab the CPU during that time interval.

Between *spin_unlock_irq* and *schedule* the syscall can be interrupted and preempted, so the other process can have enough time to send a signal which is not blocked to the process

But in this case, the signal will be lost, because the process schedule after the signal is delivered.

That's why sigsuspend should be atomical, but it's NOT according the its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

*sigsuspend* implementation is correct, but the explanation in ULK is seems to be misleading.

When process executes kernel code, that execution is never interrupted by the user's signals. Instead, such signals are accumulated inside *current* task structure. At the moment the process leaves kernel code and returns to the user one, all signals accumulated(and not blocked) are fired.

*schedule()* kernel's function checks, whether some signals are accumulated. If they are, and `current->state` is TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE, *schedule()* returns. So all signals collected before `schedule()` call are not lost.

Atomicity of *sigsuspend()* system call means that if signals, temporary unblocked by the call, are emitted, then that **call will garantee see them and return**. Such atomicity is simply achived by placing both unblocking and checking signals inside same kernel function.

Comment: u'r right. I've read entry.S again. I misunderstood that when return from interrupt to kernel path (in nested kernel path case), kernel will handle pending signal. Actually only (before) return to user space, kernel will handle pending signal. Thx